# Java get set one liner

Tags: java

I'd like to do a get and set if null like so.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
...
String test = foo.getTest() == null ? foo.setTest("this") : foo.getTest();
```

The thing is set is a void method. What the right way to set this `String test` to ?

Comment: You retrieve the value from `getTest()` twice, this is inefficient.

Comment: This is pseudo code the explain the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a one liner.

```
String test = foo.getTest();
if (test == null) {
    test = "this";
    foo.setTest(test);
}
```

Comment: Ya I think is might be the best for readability. But was still wondering if it was possible as a one liner.

Comment: @StenKin Well, you could put all that on one line, but you can't do it with a conditional operator without making the `set` method return something other than `void`.